# PySpark : AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'values'

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm a newbie in PySpark and I want to translate the following scripts which are pythonic into pyspark:

```py
api_param_df = pd.DataFrame([[row[0][0], np.nan] if row[0][1] == '' else row[0] for row in http_path.values], columns=["api", "param"])
df = pd.concat([df['raw'], api_param_df], axis=1)
```

but I face the following error, which error trackback is following:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-df055fb7d6a1> in <module>()
     21 # Notice we also make \? and the second capture group optional so that when there are no query parameters in http path, it returns NaN.
     22 
---> 23 api_param_df = pd.DataFrame([[row[0][0], np.nan] if row[0][1] == '' else row[0] for row in http_path.values], columns=["api", "param"])
     24 df = pd.concat([df['raw'], api_param_df], axis=1)
     25 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   1642         if name not in self.columns:
   1643             raise AttributeError(
-> 1644                 "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__.__name__, name))
   1645         jc = self._jdf.apply(name)
   1646         return Column(jc)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'values'
```

The full script is as follow, and explanations are commented for using `regex` to apply on the certain column `http_path` in `df` to parse `api` and `param` and merge/concat them to df again.

```py
#Extract features from http_path ["API URL", "URL parameters"]

regex = r'([^\?]+)\?*(.*)'
http_path = df.filter(df['http_path'].rlike(regex))

#                   http_path
#0  https://example.org/path/to/file?param=42#frag...
#1  https://example.org/path/to/file

#                 api                              param
#0  https://example.org/path/to/file         param=42#fragment
#1  https://example.org/path/to/file                NaN

#where in regex pattern:

#- (?:https?://[^/]+/)? optionally matches domain but doesn't capture it
#- (?P<api>[^?]+) matches everything up to ?
#- \? matches ? literally
#- (?P<param>.+) matches everything after ?

# Notice we also make \? and the second capture group optional so that when there are no query parameters in http_path, it returns NaN.

api_param_df = pd.DataFrame([[row[0][0], np.nan] if row[0][1] == '' else row[0] for row in http_path.values], columns=["api", "param"])
df = pd.concat([df['raw'], api_param_df], axis=1)

df
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is valid with Pandas DataFrames but that attribute doesn't exist for the PySpark created DataFrames. You can check out [this link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.html) for the documentation.

Usually, the `collect()` method or the `.rdd` attribute would help you with these tasks.

You can use the following snippet to produce the desired result:

```
http_path = sdf.rdd.map(lambda row: row['http_path'].split('?'))
api_param_df = pd.DataFrame([[row[0], np.nan] if len(row) == 1 else row for row in http_path.collect()], columns=["api", "param"])
sdf = pd.concat([sdf.toPandas()['raw'], api_param_df], axis=1)
```

Note that I removed the comments to make it more readable and I've also substituted the `regex` with a simple split.